# Build dynamic ActiveRecord query in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to know how to successfully set out a dynamic Active Record query based on whether the params are present/exist.

I have this query

```
Animal.joins(:user).where(animal_type: params[:animal_type], rehomed: params[:rehomed], users: {town: params[:animal_town]})
```

I have tried something along these lines, but my syntax is all wrong, I believe:

```
conditions = []
conditions << [ animal_type: params[:animal_type], ] if params[:animal_type].present?
conditions << [ rehomed: params[:rehomed], ] if params[:rehomed].present?
conditions << [ users: {town: params[:animal_town]} ] if params[:animal_town].present?
@animals = Animal.joins(:user).where(conditions)
```

I don't want to put it all in a nested hash, do I?

Comment: Why you don't want to put it in nested hash? It should be in nested hash.

Comment: In your case, `where` accepts a hash anyway. So using strong parameters and `params` hash itself could be way to go.

Comment: ok maybe im being slow today but to access the conditions hash i would do `where(conditions: conditions)`  ?

Comment: Something like `where(params)` but **don't do this**, filter `params` with Rails' `permit`, `require` and the likes: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters .

Comment: @Richlewis yes, you'd do `where(conditions: conditions)`. Why don't you try it before asking BTW?

Comment: @MarekLipka apologies, i didn't even think until reading everything back through and reading the comments

Comment: @MarekLipka so after trying conditions: conditions i get  column animals.conditions does not exist

Comment: @Richlewis probably you have already `conditions` key in your `conditions` hash, I don't know how exactly you define this hash, so I couldn't predict this. If so, you should do: `where(conditions)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to do:

```
conditions = {}
conditions.merge!(animal_type: params[:animal_type]) if params[:animal_type].present?
conditions.merge!(rehomed: params[:rehomed]) if params[:rehomed].present?
conditions.merge!(users: {town: params[:animal_town]}) if params[:animal_town].present?

@animals = Animal.joins(:user).where(conditions)
```

Comment: It is more efficient to avoid merge!: conditions[:animal_type]= params[:animal_type]

Answer (score 2):

I would do somethink like this:

```
scope = Animal.joins(:user)
scope = scope.where(animal_type: params[:animal_type])     if params[:animal_type].present?
scope = scope.where(rehomed: params[:rehomed])             if params[:rehomed].present?
scope = scope.where(users: { town: params[:animal_town] }) if params[:animal_town].present?

@animals = scope
```

Further improvements: Move building of the scope into a method in the Animal model:

```
# in controller
@animals = Animal.find_by_query(params.slice(:animal_type, :rehomed, :animal_town))

# in Animal model
def self.find_by_query(query = {})
  query.reject { |_, v| v.blank? }

  scope = joins(:user)
  scope = scope.where(animal_type: query[:animal_type])     if query[:animal_type]
  scope = scope.where(rehomed: query[:rehomed])             if query[:rehomed]
  scope = scope.where(users: { town: query[:animal_town] }) if query[:animal_town]
  scope
end
```